# Standalone routing library?

Tags: php, frameworks, routes

Bascially over years I have developed my own framework. What it lacks it's a central routing system.
I would like to integrate a standalone routing library to my framework, instead to reinvent the wheel.

Is there somewhere a standalone php routing library?
If there isn't can you suggest any guideline for its developing?

I would like something like F3 framework:

```
$route->add( 'article/view/[0-9]+' );  //> Call Article->view(); (website.net/article/id/123)
$route->add( 'email', 'email.php' ); //> Run email.php (website.net/email)
```

### Edit

I have developed on my own. Here the example usage:

```php
   // index.php

   require 'router.php';

   $router = new Router();

   $router
     //> It will require controllers/article.php and call one of the view,etc method
     ->add('(article)/(view|edit|delete|add)/([0-9]+)')

     //> Same thing as before, but this time we use underscore as separator
     //> It will require controllers/entry.php and call view method
     ->add('(entry)_(view)_([0-9]+)')

     //> Or you can require custom file like this
     ->add( '(myCustomPage)' , '/controllers/myCustomPath/myPage.php' )

     ->dispatch();
```

If you need a simple controller you can run directy a function without having to specify a class. Example:

```
   // myCustomController.php
   function myCustomController($id) {
     echo 'I am the Custom Controller';
   }

   // index.php
   $router
      ->add('(myCustomController)/([0-9]+)');

   // The routing system will detect there is a function and will call it directly.
   // Otherwise will just instanciate a new myCustomController() object
```

You can of course use Search Engine Friendly URLs like this:

```
   //> This will match something like this: article/123/your-title-here
   ->add('(article)/([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9-]+')
```

You can run custom method from custom controller like this:

```
   ->add('(ctrlname)/(methodname)/(params)', array('CustomControllerName','CustomMethod') );
```

Source: http://pastebin.com/9F02GEyN

Comment: Define "routing". Routing of what?

Comment: @Pekka: Sorry, added an example

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115629/simplest-php-routing-framework

Comment: @jar: already saw that, not very useful in my case :( it's just a theorical description of it

Comment: Quite a few libs are mentioned throughout the thread.

Comment: @jar: they mention full framework like kohanaphp or F3. Anyway to be more clear I have answered my question with a routing lib i have just found

Comment: I am developing my own library, I will publish it soon. Hope to get some feedback

Comment: Published, if you can take a look

Comment: If you are sure you want honest feedback and can take a bit of criticism feel free to ping me in [PHP chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) with a github link when you think you are ready for it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may either use [Symfony Routing component](https://packagist.org/packages/symfony/routing), or brilliant [klein.php](https://github.com/chriso/klein.php) router, which is a Sinatra-inspired tool wrapped in a single PHP file.